# How do I open up and examine a Moss webpart?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, reflection, moss, web-parts

I want to look into one of the out of the box MOSS 2007 webparts and examine the code. After that I want to replicate some of the functionality and add some of my own. Any techniques?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All SharePoint DLL's can be found in the C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\ISAPI folder, use reflector to inspect the code. Some code may be obfuscated though...

Comment: thanks. More specifically for those looking at the controls wthin sharepoint, pay attention to the Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls namespace in the Microsoft.SharePoint.dll assembly

Answer (score 1):

Try .NET Reflector (free!) from http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/ . Depending on which web part it is, you can inherit and extend. If the web part is sealed, you could consume/adapt it, or plainly roll your own with inspiration from what source code .NET reflector generated for you. But it really depends on, what you want - a lot of web parts in MOSS can be configured in a lot of ways using plain XML configuration .webpart-files.

Comment: .dwp is some kind of common format. If I can get that open I'm sure reflector would reveal the secrets

Comment: My mistake. I have to find the actual assembly to get the code.. the .dwp one gets is only the XML reference to the .dll on the server.

Comment: Right - most SharePoint DLLs are stored in the GAC.

Comment: You can find the Micosoft.SharePoint.dll assembly in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\ISAPI\